# Pass the local image path as a prop between two functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm working on a project in react-native, where I have troubles of understanding how props works between functional components. My requirement is to create a re-usable button component where I can just pass the image location in the resource file inside my project, so it'll create the button for me. For some reason if i give the required location manually, it will work and create the button for me, but if i\I pass the location as a prop from where I create it wont work for some reason. My code as bellow.

Button component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

const ButtonWithImage = (props) => {
    const {buttonStyle} = styles;
    const clickEvent = () => {}

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress= {clickEvent}style={buttonStyle}>
            <Image 
                source={props.imagePath} 
                style={styles.ImageIconStyle} 
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        //alignSelf:'stretch',
        height: 50,
        width:50,
        paddingTop:0,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
};

export default ButtonWithImage;
```

Place where I create the button and pass the prop

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import FooterIcons from './ButtonWithImage'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
            <FooterIcons imagePath = {'./images/homeButton/homeBtn.png'} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    footerStyle: {
        height: 60,
        width: 100,
        // justifyContent:'flex-start'
    },
});

export default Footer;
```

Comment: you might have a typo in your code - arguments are `props` and you try to pass `prop.imagePath`

Comment: i did sir but still same effect, then i put a console log to see, seems render method runs before it sets the argument parameters i assume

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not possible since you want to require an image with a local path
 `<Image source={require(props.path)} />` and this does not work because ***require*** can only take string literal as an argument.

This means that you will have to do:

```
<FooterIcons imagePath = {require('./images/homeButton/homeBtn.png')} 
/>
```

To make it work.
And don't forget to give your image a **width** and **height**.

**OR**

You can do it in a way which works good for apps that does not have big amounts of images, because we will preload them:

1- Make an assets javascript file assets.js , this file should require all your local images, something like this:

```
const assetsObject = {
  homeIcon: require('./images/homeButton/homeBtn.png')
  boatIcon: require('./images/homeButton/boat.png')
  ....
  ...
}
module.exports = assetsObject
```

2- Now you need to require this file in your ButtonWithImage.js file

```
const assets = require('./assets.js')

const ButtonWithImage = (props) => {
  const {buttonStyle} = styles;
  const clickEvent = () => {}

  return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress= {clickEvent}style={buttonStyle}>
         <Image 
            source={assets[props.imagePath]} 
            style={styles.ImageIconStyle} 
         />
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

3- The props you send to ButtonWithImage should be on of the keys of the assetsObject we created `'homeIcon'` or `'boatIcon'` ..etc

```
const Footer = () => {
return (
    <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
        <FooterIcons imagePath = {'homeIcon'} />
    </View>
);
};
```

4- Don't forget to give your image a **width** and **height**

Thats it, and i suggest not calling the prop imagePath anymore, maybe just image.

Comment: this sounds like a legit answer, but for some reason it throws some errors, can u please check the code again in case u missing something sir

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the value as you pass other pros.

```
import picture from 'linkOfYourImage.png';

function Func() { 
<YourComponent imgLink={picture }/>
}
```